# select multiple ids for a slideToggle JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have s slideToggle function like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".widget-content-box").slideUp(); // $(".widget-content-box").hide()
$("#goal1").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next().slideToggle("slow");
 });
})
```

I am executing the click function on an id of #goal1 and would like to have multiple slideToggles, but rather than use #goal1, #goal2, #goal3 etc what can I use? Is it id plus attr? but how would i set that out in the code, or where can I find the resource to find out?

any help appreciated

Comment: what you mean by "multiple slide toggles" ? on one click animate multiple elements? + a HTML sample would be really useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot modify your HTML adding classes as already suggested, 
you could use the "starts with" selector `^`:

```
$("[id^=goal]").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next().slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your elements a `goal` class, then:

```
$(".goal").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().next().slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: think my question wasnt clear enough, i would like multiple slideToggles, have edited

Comment: Please provide your HTML as well.

Comment: thanks for your help, @roXon had the answer i was looking for